# How can I perform an intelligent EF query on an IEnumerable of T?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a collection of objects, which I got from a few queries and combined them.

Here's an example in PSEUDO code:

```
List<myObj> list = new List<myObj>();

list.add(myContext.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS WHERE CONTAINS("DOGS" NEAR "CATS", 5, 3);
list.add(myContext.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS WHERE CONTAINS("FISH" NEAR "WATER", 2, 1);
list.add(myContext.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS WHERE NAME = "Fluffkins");
```

I'm fairly sure I can't do an `.Include()` on this but if there's a way I'm interested.

I want to enumerate through, and look at a specific property. I can do a foreach and examine `myObj.prop1.prop2` in each object, but this will result in a sql query for each object.

```
foreach(var x in myEnumerableCollection)
{
   var y = x.prop1.prop2 // Not iqueryable so I couldn't include, this means it does a query every time
}
```

The standard solution to this is to do a `.Include()` however I am unable to do that due to the way I built up the collection of objects - it came from multiple inline SQL queries.

The quick and dirty way would probably be to construct a SQL query myself, something like:

`SELECT * from myObjType inner join prop1 on ... inner join prop2 on ...`

however tracking that as entity objects may be problematic, and also inline sql isn't great compared to using entity objects.

SO I guess I'm wondering if I can somehow perform an `.Include` or similar on my `IEnumerable<T>` to have EF behind the scenes populate the properties in a single query so the foreach evaluates faster.

Any ideas?

Edit: Problem with `.SqlQuery<T>` is that it doesn't return `IQueryable<T>` so that sort of rules out any chaining and lazy evaluation.

Comment: Can you actually post some code?

Comment: Sure, but if you need me to write out how to enumerate through a collection and access a property, I'm not sure you'll be able to help - added the code

Comment: @SLC That's not the code that matters.  What matters is what you're doing to end up with your `IEnumerable`.  Depending on how it's constructed this may be impossible, perhaps you can modify it to allow you to do what you need, and perhaps one could leverage how it was constructed to do something that couldn't be done to an arbitrary `IEnumerable` (i.e. casting it back to an `IQueryable` and then acting on that).  If you only have an `IEnumerable`, and that's all that's known, then the problem can't be solved.  It's that simple.

Comment: Edited to show roughly how I do it, although I actually call generic functions to execute each query.

Comment: If you are looking for help... how about loosing the flippant attitude... read the guidelines of how to write a post.. and have some manners. What I needed to see was how you ended up with an IEnumerable, your post was not clear and in places... did not make sense.

Comment: You're the one who said 'Can you actually post some code?' which is both sarcastic and just some copy+paste response that showed you hadn't really read the question.

Comment: Well good luck getting an answer to your question. It looks to me like you might be waiting a while.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351755.aspx) method in LINQ with the following signature:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source1,
    IEnumerable<TSource> source2
)
```

Instead of building a collection of these objects, you could use this to join your queries together into an `IQueryable<T>` that you can use in the usual way (`.Include()`).

Comment: I'ved checked and it seems that `SqlQuery` doesn't return an IQueryable, it just returns `IEnumerable`, even though the entities it returns are tracked if used with a generic `<T>`.

Comment: Why are you using SQL Query instead of using EF's LINQ capability? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Yes, EF doesn't support full text search, so you have to do the queries manually. It's quite unfortunate :(